# Binary search algorithm accepts data not in the dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, binary-search

I'm trying to write a binary search algorithm, and I think it is mostly working, but it allows you to use data that isn't inside the dataset

I was trying to do it without using functions, and just using print to get the result, but I changed to using using a function and returning the value, which still doesn't work

```
def find(): #I'm not sure how to use the brackets here to contain a variable so this could be part of the problem
    dataset = [0, 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10]
    mi = 0
    ma = len(dataset)

    target = int(input("what are you looking for?"))

    while mi < ma:
        midpt = int((mi + ma) / 2)
        if dataset[midpt]== target:
            return target

        elif dataset[midpt] > target:
            ma = midpt - 1
            return target

        elif dataset[midpt] < target:
            ma = midpt + 1
            return target
#I didn't completely know how to do this next bit, so it may well be the issue, but as it contains no errors I just went with it

found = find() 
print(found)
```

I expect the output when you input 5, to be 5, and when you input anything above 10 to return an error. If you input 5, it will output 5, but if you input say 11, it will just output 11. This seems to me that it isn't really working at all and it just returns target as the input. Does anyone know if it just isn't working or it isn't using the dataset and if so what is wrong?

Comment: A "return" ends a function and returns the given value. You have too many of them.

Comment: @MichaelButscher how do I tell it to stop after each block then?

Comment: You are right when you think it's just returning the input. On the first pass, you look at the midpoint, then ignore it and immediately return the original input. You already have a while loop, let it do its job.

Comment: ps: pass target as a function parameter. This allows you to unit test.

Comment: @KennyOstrom When I do this, I get error TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'

Comment: Maybe you did it wrong. The error message tells you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tasks: find the value, and return it. Do those in sequence.

The `while` loop is trying to maintain the invariant that min, max sandwich the target value.
It would be worth your while to **verify** that before you start looping --
verify that first value `<=` target and target `<=` last value.

BTW, it doesn't make a big difference, but
the usual API would be for `find()` to return the *index* of the found target value.
A sample input of `list(range(0, 11, 2))` would be convenient for testing against.

The big problem with your current code is you wanted to squish
the target value between `mi` and `ma`,
yet you only ever change `ma`.

As soon as those two variables are identical,
then you're in a good position to compare target to the value they point at,
and return an appropriate value.